# Exchange or return the product with a different one

Tags: e-commerce, ux-field, ux-designer

I work on a website that sells clothes on the Internet
Where the user requests a product (trousers - a T-shirt ... etc.) and upon receiving the product, he has a period of 15 days to replace the product or return the product and take the money

The problem here is how can I display the two buttons (return / exchange) and return one product, for example, out of 5 products in the same order, knowing that it is possible to exchange between 1500 different products

Answer (score 2):

Having an order tracker in "My User Account" is enough. In this space, there can be a dropdown with each purchase and CTA buttons for actions

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could have the return button only. When the user has returned the item, the money is moved into their "wallet". This way you are also certain that you have the returned item in stock before returning their money.

This wallet system can then be used by the user to buy other items. Or returned into their bank accounts. The reason you want to use a flow like this is to encourage users to keep the money within your systems so that you reduce how much money is being bleed out.